# Get WebDriver's implicitly_wait value?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

How can I get value of implicit wait that has been set before?

In a method which runs at start of each test, I need to test for a set of elements of which normally only one is expected to exist.  Since for rest of tests, what works best is value about 20 seconds, this means that the mentioned method would take from 20 (the first element almost never exists) to n-1 * 20 seconds!

So what I need to do is store the value, change it to something like 1s and after the "survey", set it back to what it was.  But I can't find any attribute where this is stored and calling `implicitly_wait()` without arguments raises TypeError.  (Most that I can do now is have a global default and use it, but that's counter-intuitive, counter-flexible and dumb. :))

So is there a way how I can retrieve the current value?

(I'm using Python 2.6, Selenium Server 2.32 and FireFoxProfile)

Comment: I haven't found way to get the value. However, do you need to know it in the code? Can't you just set it to something small in the beginning of the method and again back to larger value at the end of it?

Comment: @Edu That's what I do now (I use global default for "larger value"), but the issue is that if someone sets the value to something arbitrary and then uses my method, *their* value is lost.

Comment: Oh, I see. Can you implement the checking in the method in another way? If something shouldn't exist on a page, I normally wait for some element that is added last to the page and then verify that the others are not seen in the source code (or in your case that some of them exists). This is much faster than waiting for timeouts on non-existing elements.